# MySQL : how to divide database into two disks?

Tags: mysql, sql, tomcat7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a database installed in C:\ and I created an other database in C:\ to log users' data because the data size is very big, So I want to save it somewhere else.

Then I moved the second database with its data to D:\ through a **symbolic link** file to point out the new directory.

> Here the file name : archive_file.sym
>
> And here its content : D:\MySQLData\data\archive_db
>
> archive_db : is the name of my second database

the problem is when I executed a MySQL command to see the content of one of the tables in the seconde database:

> use 'archive_db';
>
> select * from 'log_user';

I've got this error :

> 'log_user' Table doesn't exist

I've tried symbolique_link throughout MySQL documentation :
[Using Symbolic Links for Databases on Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-symbolic-links.html).

Any advices ? Any idea how to proceed otherwise?

I'm working on Windows server 2008-r2 , MySQL server version 5.6

Comment: You are using single quotes where no quotes at all are needed.  If you desperately have the need to include quotes, use backticks.  I vote to close these questions as typographical errors.

Comment: Thx but I've got the same error after executing an interface command through MySQL workbench software . So there is no doubt in the command correctness.